# Can we change Normal Activities in android to Action Bar activities

Tags: android

I developed an app, but now I want to change all the Activities.
They all should have an ActionBar.

Can I directly convert my code by extending the existing Activities to get an  ActionBar?

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: `can i convert directly by extending activities as action bar` Yup. Why not???

Answer (score 0):

-Agree with above answer. doing as per follow ..

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

}
```

-And..You have to add this code into your `manifest` file

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

-Under `application` tag

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can, like this, just you will need is Android Support Library (AppCompat lib)

public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity

And also do necessary changes regarding with ActionBar, you can get ActionBar object like ,

ActionBar mAction = getSupportActionBar();

mAction.setTitle("Your Title");

Comment: public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, OnDataListener ,if i extend actionbar its showing errors in  fragmentactivity.